# Running go install results in error

Tags: windows, go, build

I installed go on Windows. GOPATH is set to this:

```
    c:\go-workspace
```

I have file called login.go in this directory:

```
    C:\go-workspace\src\github.com\llnw\login
```

login.go contains this:

```
    package main
    func main() {
      fmt.Printf("login\n")
    }
```

I tried the following to build:

```
    go build github.com/llnw/login/login
```

But I get this error:

```
    can't load package: package github.com/llnw/login/login: cannot find package "github.com/llnw/login/login" in any of:
    C:\Go\src\github.com\llnw\login\login (from $GOROOT)
    C:\go-workspace\src\github.com\llnw\login\login (from $GOPATH)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your package is `github.com/llnw/login` and not `github.com/llnw/login/login`, just execute `go build github.com/llnw/login`

Comment: Thanks, Yandry. You answered the question but there is no checkmark so I can't indicate that you answered it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `go build -h`:

> ```
> usage: build [-o output] [-i] [build flags] [packages]
>
> Build compiles the packages named by the import paths,
> along with their dependencies, but it does not install the results.
>
> If the arguments to build are a list of .go files, build treats
> them as a list of source files specifying a single package.
> ```

In your example, `github.com/llnw/login/login` looks neither like a package, nor a list of `.go` files. Probably you're looking for this:

```
go build github.com/llnw/login
```

Assuming that when you execute this command, the relative path `github.com/llnw/login` exists.